# Long-term usage of branches with "git worktree"

Tags: git, version-control, git-worktree

I was looking into git's "new" `worktree` feature as it seems to fit really neatly into a problem I usually face: the need to work in multiple branches simultaneously (some of them are short-lived while others really long-lived).

I'll generally have to work for a couple of hours on `release_a branch` and then fix something on `release_x branch` and then a bit on `release_h branch`. As I'm lazy, what I end up doing is having multiple copies of my git repository set up with Intellij, so I don't need to be constantly switching branches here and there.

When I heard about git's `worktree` command I thought it was just what I was looking for -- a way to have a single repo have multiple working directories. And as a big plus, that would mean that I no longer would actually have to push stuff every time I changed something on a branch just for the sake of having another one pull it (as for instance, for an hotfix). I could just locally merge them.

Is my understanding of what git's `worktree` correct?

I've been playing with it but I can't really get how it works for my purposes. It seems that by default it will create the worktrees on its root folder, but that if I do a `git add .` those same folders will be included in the commit.

This is how I'm creating a worktree for an already existing branch `my_branch` (assume I'm currently @ `master`):

```
git worktree add my_branch my_branch
```

So my questions is twofold:

1. Is it possible / correct to apply multiple worktrees for long-time branches, or is it just something that makes sense temporarily?
2. How should I then properly delete my unneeded worktrees?
3. Should I have these worktrees existing inside or outside my main git repository?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And as a big plus, that would mean that I no longer would actually have to push stuff every time I changed something on a branch just for the sake of having another one pull it (as for instance, for an hotfix). I could just locally merge them.

You can already merge the branches locally: you just have to checkout the destination branch first.
If you have multiple local checked out folders of the same repo, yes, you would need to push/pull between them.

With [`git worktree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree), instead of a checkout of the destination branch (to do the merge), or instead of pushing to another checked out folder of the same repo, you would need to `cd /path/to/destination/branch` (where it is *already* checked out).

The idea is to have:

- `/path/to/your/repo` (with one branch like master checked out)
- `/path/to/your/Branch1` (*outside* of the repo, but linked back to the repos through the `git worktree` text symlink mechanism)
- `/path/to/your/Branch2`, ...and so on.

Then the doc is clear:

> **When you are done with a linked working tree you can simply delete it**.
>
> The working tree’s administrative files in the repository ([see "DETAILS" below](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree#_details)) will eventually be removed automatically (see `gc.worktreePruneExpire` in [`git-config`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config)).
> Or you can run `git worktree prune` in the main or any linked working tree to clean up any stale administrative files.

Comment: "You can already merge the branches locally: you just have to checkout the destination branch first. " If you're working with two (or more, one for each branch you're currently working with) local repositories, you will always have to push & pull from one repo to the other. Am I right?

Comment: @devouredelysium No, you only have to commit in your current branch, checkout the destination branch, and merge from the previous branch. push/pull are only there to publish your work for other to consume. Merge is a local operation: you have everything you need locally.

Comment: I think we are talking past each other. Before git's worktree command was available in git 2.5, the only way to achieve multiple checked out branches simultaneously is with multiple repositories. And the only way to actually get the changes from one branch in repo A seen in repo B is by pushing & pulling. Correct?

Comment: @devouredelysium right: if you want tp have multiple folder, then yes, you would have multiple repos and the need for push/pull. But that is what git 2.5+ worktree is solving. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Okay, the structure of directories you propose is pretty much what I was assuming would make sense. My next question is: when I'm done with a given branch, can I just erase it from disk or should I use some `worktree` command? I've looked up to purge, but nothing interesting seems to come out from it.

Comment: @devouredelysium yes, you can delete. The doc mentions: "When you are done with a linked working tree you can simply delete it."